# Merging data with groups of identical names via data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have 2 data tables that I would like to merge using `data.table` library. So far, I am getting a merged data with a lot of duplicates involved. The dummy code that I use can be found below:

```
df <- data.frame("Code" = c(rep("REM",5),rep("REV",5),rep("RET",5)),"Num" = c(sample(15)))
df2 <- data.frame("Code" = c(rep("REM",5),rep("REV",5),rep("RET",5)),"Num" = c(sample(15)))
dt <- data.table(df)
dt2 <- data.table(df2)
merge(dt, dt2, by="Code", all = TRUE, allow.cartesian = TRUE)
```

As mentioned above, I am get duplicates which I would like to exclude. Desired output:

```
dfX <- data.frame("Code" = c(rep("REM",5),rep("REV",5),rep("RET",5)),"Num" = df[,2],"Num2"=df2[,2])
```

Comment: You've got `all = TRUE` in there - sounds like that's not what you're after.

Comment: You also don't have any unique indicators that are in there to clarify which value in the shared column should be matched on - so for e.g. it won't know which `REM` you want to match. You would need some kind of ID or other key to ensure you are matching the right values.

Comment: Otherwise, your desired output just looks like a `cbind()`.

Comment: @Megan Thanks for that! I've added an indication column to each data table and this get rid of duplicates.However, the extra "Code" columns remain. Since I would like to merge about 20 data tables, I would imagine I would get 20 repeated columns. Is there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: Do you a) not want the Code column at all in the end product, b) want the Code column but not have it repeated? Try excluding the column when you are merging, for e.g. `dt3 <- merge(dt, dt2[, c("ID", "Num")], by = "ID"`, or just remove the Code column before merging if you don't want it at all.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot that I can exclude columns from tables. Thanks, that would do it!